# How can I resolve this error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, data-science

I am using the learning curve code path that is mentioned in this link.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html

I am getting the error below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-f71104873302> in <module>
    132 cv = KFold(n_splits=15, random_state=42, shuffle=False)
    133 plot_learning_curve(bag, title, X, y, axes=axes[:, 0], ylim=(0.7, 1.01),
--> 134                     cv=cv, n_jobs=4)
    135 
    136 title = r"Learning Curves LightGBM Classifier"

<ipython-input-41-f71104873302> in plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, X, y, axes, ylim, cv, n_jobs, train_sizes)
     78     axes[0].set_ylabel("Score")
     79 
---> 80     train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores, fit_times= learning_curve(estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs,train_sizes=train_sizes)
     81     train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
     82     train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)
```

Please help me solve this issue. I am using the exact same code for plotting with different models but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: I never worked with this library and was able to find the problem in less than 1 minute: Follow the link you've given us in your question. From there follow the link to `learning_curve`, Read the documentation concerning the return values. Find the solution.

Comment: You are *not* using the exact same code; please look closer; Plus, SO does not work by pointing to an external code repo - please post the relevant code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores, fit_times
```

To:

```
train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores, fit_times, _
```

**Edit:**

Inital answer was wrong because the example for sklearn uses `return_times` parameter when calling `learning_curve` which will return two additional variables (`fit_times`, `score_times`). In this case, the parameter was not being used and the sklearn version used, only returned 3 values.

`return_times` is only avaiable from `0.22.2`

Comment: I am sorry you are correct, according to the docs, it will return 3 values  if you set parameter  `return_times` in `learning_curve` function since you are not using that parameter, it will return only 3. doc https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.learning_curve

Comment: If I use return times then it gives me the following error:

Comment: TypeError: learning_curve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_times'

Comment: What is the sklearn version you are using `print(sklearn.__version__)` ?

Comment: 0.21.2 i am so sorry, I got it